# Book about a teenager who steps though a painting on to a ship

Tags: story-identification, parallel-universe, pirates

I don't have too much information but I'm looking to identify a series of books that I read back in the late 80's early 90s.  The main character is a teenager who steps through a painting onto a ship, where he's part of the crew.  They are constantly fighting a specific pirate.

I'm pretty sure there's a scene where to scare off a bear he has to shout really loud.

Comment: Can't help but think of [The Chronicles of Narnia: The Voyage of the Dawn Treader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Voyage_of_the_Dawn_Treader)

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PortalPicture

Comment: @NominSim I can see why that would jump out when you mention it, but that's not it, not a narnia book.  Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: @MarkBeadles good list there, but i don't see the book I'm looking for :(

Comment: That seems to almost sound like a variation of Peter Pan.

Comment: @ForceFlow no flying that I can recall or Wendy Bird ;)

Comment: i know exactly what your thinking of , and on my life i cant seem to get it , what i do know is , its none of the above ie-chronicles of narnia , its much older , definitely early 80s , maybe even late 70s , but im intrigued myself because im certain ive seen it , and was moved enough to reply to this question 35 ys or so after .dillon1462

Comment: @dillon1462 you're almost teasing ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are talking about the [Buccaneers](https://www.goodreads.com/series/134441-buccaneers) series by Sheila K. McCullagh.

> When Nicholas looks at the picture Great Uncle Jeremy left him, he finds himself climbing through the shining ring to the land of Ramir and the buccaneers on the The Silver Dolphin. Can he help Captain Harken and his crew in their fight against the Dragon Men...?

They were very short, each volume only 60-odd pages.

Comment: Thanks for coming back with an answer, I'll check these out, so far it looks like they fit...